# Vectorize Moving Window with Past Iterations

Tags: r, loops, vectorization

Given a very large data set (>1million observations), and am trying to vectorize my logic but haven't found the R-ified way to solve it.

The problem is for every time I have a "Bad" observation in a variable, I need to check the previous 5 observations for "Good" indicators. "Bad" observations are kept so long as there are 5 "Good" ones preceding it. If there are "Bad" ones within the 5 observation moving window then that observation will eventually be dropped from analysis.

So far I have tried using a for loop with `ifelse()` logic. The logic checks out, but with R's processing it takes hours to complete. I have looked into the `zoo` package for rolling windows but am not applying aggregate functions like `mean()` or `sum()`. I have also looked into `apply()`, `lapply()`, etc. but haven't been able to make them work.

This is my code so for the for loop. Let `df$Observation` be the initial designation of Good vs Bad, and let `df$Result`be the determination of whether we keep or drop the observation.

**Edit**

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(Observation = sample(c("Good", "Bad"), 1000, T, c(0.9,0.1)))

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  ifelse(
    df$Observation[i] == "Good",
    df$Result[i] <- "Keep",
    ifelse(
      df$Observation[i] == "Bad" &
        df$Observation[i-1] == "Good" &
        df$Observation[i-2] == "Good" &
        df$Observation[i-3] == "Good" &
        df$Observation[i-4] == "Good",
      df$Result[i] <- "Keep",
      df$Result[i] <- "Drop"
    )
  )
}
```

Example desired result:

```
df[385:393,]

    Observation Result
385        Good   Keep
386        Good   Keep
387        Good   Keep
388        Good   Keep
389        Good   Keep
390         Bad   Keep
391        Good   Keep
392        Good   Keep
393         Bad   Drop
```

The code works as expected but I need a more efficient way to execute it in R. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

First I set the seed, created some sample data and opened necessary packages.

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(Observation = sample(c("Good", "Bad"), 1000, T, c(0.9,0.1)))
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
```

At first I lag one row. From there, I calculate the `rollmax` for that lagged row and the previous four rows. Then I compare this `rollmax` to `1`. If this evaluates to `TRUE` AND the current row equals `"Bad"`, `Result` will be `"Drop"`, else it will be `"KEEP"`.

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(Result = if_else(rollmax(lag(Observation) == "Bad", 5, fill = 0, align = "right") == 1 & Observation == "Bad", "Drop", "Keep"))
```

This way it will match your expected output:

```
 df2[385:393,]
    Observation Result
385        Good   Keep
386        Good   Keep
387        Good   Keep
388        Good   Keep
389        Good   Keep
390         Bad   Keep
391        Good   Keep
392        Good   Keep
393         Bad   Drop
```

Comment: Hi Lennyy, thanks for the suggestion. When I run this it seems to remove all "Bad"s regardless of the prior 5 check. I want to be sure I keep the ones that pass the check. I also incorporated your sample df above with desired output.

Comment: Hi, sorry I slightly misunderstood your question. Please see my updated post.

Comment: Not a problem, thank you for supplying the updated solution!

Answer (score 2):

I like `zoo` for this. It all seems to match except for the first instance of bad (only 3 obs prior). You could adjust the logic to keep that one using `fill = 4`

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

df_decision <-
  df %>% 
  mutate(
    good_ind = as.integer(Observation == "Good"),
    good_count = rollsum(good_ind, 5, align = "right", fill = good_ind),
    result =ifelse(good_ind == 1 | good_count >= 4, "keep", "drop")
  )
```

Comment: Hi yake84, thank you for supplying this solution! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If you replace the loop with some `dplyr` functions, things really speed up. Just be careful about the treatment of the first 5 rows. The `dplyr` version will drop any 'Bad' observations in the first 5 rows, whereas your loop will keep them. You can add some more logic to the `case_when` if you need to.

```
library(tictoc)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(Observation = sample(c("Good", "Bad"), 10000, TRUE, c(0.9,0.1)))
df2 <- df

tic("loop")
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  ifelse(
    df$Observation[i] == "Good",
    df$Result[i] <- "Keep",
    ifelse(
      df$Observation[i] == "Bad" &
        df$Observation[i-1] == "Good" &
        df$Observation[i-2] == "Good" &
        df$Observation[i-3] == "Good" &
        df$Observation[i-4] == "Good",
      df$Result[i] <- "Keep",
      df$Result[i] <- "Drop"
    )
  )
}
toc() # 3.9s

tic("dplyr")
df2 <- df2 %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    L1 = dplyr::lag(Observation, 1),
    L2 = dplyr::lag(Observation, 2),
    L3 = dplyr::lag(Observation, 3),
    L4 = dplyr::lag(Observation, 4),
    L5 = dplyr::lag(Observation, 5),
    Result = dplyr::case_when(
      Observation == "Good" ~ "Keep",
      L1 == "Good" & 
        L2 == "Good" & 
        L3 == "Good" & 
        L4 == "Good" & 
        L5 == "Good" ~ "Keep",
      TRUE ~ "Drop"
    )
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::select(Observation, Result)
toc() # 0.08s
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! While yake84's and Lennyy's responses also both worked, this was clocked in at the fastest processing time so I'll accept this one for the answer. Encourage others to take a look at their's as well though!